# JqueryMobile Position a input text next to an icon image

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

i am new to jquery mobile and css.

refer to my jsfiddle.net/mapsv3/kWJRw/1/, if i am using icon at left side, the input text will become weird which i can't see end of input text.

Comment: Linking a jsfiddle is OK, but you should post the important parts of your code here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the width of the text boxes so that they dont overflow. here:

```
 <input style="width: 100%"  name="" id="txtEmail" placeholder="your email" value="" type="email"/>
```

you can set the width, for example, to 80%:

```
<input style="width: 80%"  name="" id="txtEmail" placeholder="your email" value="" type="email"/>
```

it will look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kWJRw/4/

Comment: other than using 'style="width: 80%"', anyways of doing it using css? i wish to maintain 100% width in JQueryMobile. I am testing it on mobile platform as well with resolution 320x480

Comment: if there's an icon occupying part of the screen, then a 100% textbox cannot fit into the page. Don't you think?